# Dynamic iframe inserted into document that is standards mode defaults to quirks mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a parent document that is currently returning `CSS1Compat` from `document.compatMode`.

When I add a blank iframe with jQuery like this:

```
$("body").append("<iframe id='test-iframe'></iframe>");
```

and check the compatMode of the new iframe like this:

```
$("#test-iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.compatMode
```

it equals `BackCompat`

This is causing case sensitivity issues later on and some other styling problems. I can't change the cases and have no control over that. Shouldn't the new iframe be the same compatMode? Is there a way to force that?

Comment: This is tested in Chrome Version 44.0.2403.155 m (64-bit)

Comment: When you add a frame with no "src" attribute, it gets a default document. There's nothing particularly useful about that document; why do you care? If you fill the frame with your own content, then the details of that are completely under your control, just like those of the containing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the browser is loading a basic html document (notice no doctype declaration):

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Since there is no doctype declared Chrome will use BackCompat mode.

If you want it to be changed to a different mode either set the src url to a html page that uses a doctype declaration, or write to the iframe and set the html to one with a doctype.

```
var myContent = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>';

$("body").append("<iframe id='test-iframe'></iframe>");
var frame = $("#test-iframe")[0];
frame.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
frame.contentWindow.document.write(myContent);
frame.contentWindow.document.close();
console.log( frame.contentWindow.document.compatMode );
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8u63dq6/1/)

Comment: Interesting because I'm using this library (https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) and it does add the doctype to the iframe. But it doesn't do it with a document.write. It does it by doing things like this doc.implementation.createDocumentType(nodeData.name, nodeData.publicId, nodeData.systemId), which when I inspect the frame it does have a doctype, but doesn't seem to be sticking. When I do the document.write as you have it seems to work.